# Maximum directional derivative and gradient

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose that a function $f(x,y)$ has a gradient $[1,3]$ at a point $P$. Give a unit vector:

1. in the direction of the maximum rate of increase of $f$ at $P$
2. in the direction of the maximum rate of decrease of $f$ at $P$
3. in a direction for which the rate of exchange of $f$ at $P$ is zero

I have no idea how to approach this. I know how to solve this only if $f$ is given. Some explanations and/or exmples would be really helpful for this particular exercise, thank you.

Comment: The gradient is already given. The max rate of increase will be in the direction of the gradient, max rate of decrease in opp direction and zero in perp direction.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you can solve this kind of problem when $f$ is given? As @MathLover just said, typically we use $f$ just to find the gradient at $P$.

Comment: @MathLover thanks, I got it now!